# Trying to find a match of two strings in a file using awk

Tags: awk, html-parsing

Hello I am trying to find a  pattern match on some HTML files using AWK but i dont seem to have any luck with it

So for my pattern to match it should have the following

```
<tr>
                    <td>Failures</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Warnings</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Errors</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Not Applicable</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Manual Checks</td>
                    <td>9</td>
                </tr>
```

Failures and Manual Checks should be zero. So in the above file failures is 0 and manual check is 9. So i need to match only when failure is 0 and manual check is 0.

SO i tried with and without escaping the new line but awk is not returning any results.

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec awk '/td\>Failures\<\/td\>\\n.*\<td\>0/ {print FILENAME}' '{}' \;
```

I have also tried other combinations like below but cant seem to figure out why awk is not going to the next line.

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec awk '/td\>Failures\<\/td\>\\n\[\^\\\<\]\+\<td\>0/ {print FILENAME}' '{}' \;
```

Can anyone please have a look and tell me what i am missing?

Comment: one issue with the current approach ... by default `awk` processes *one* line at a time which means a multiline test (`... Failures ... \n ... 0 ...`) will never find a match; one approach would have `awk` continue to process individual lines while adding logic to keep track of 2 consecutive line matches (eg, `... Failures ...` and `... 0 ...`); another approach would have `awk` process the entire file as a single 'line' (see my answer for one approach); there may be other approaches but the general issue remains ... how to process multiple lines of input as a single unit of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more reliable solution is going to be based on a tool designed to parse `html`; having said that ...

One `awk` idea using a couple custom regex patterns:

```
$ cat regex.awk
BEGIN { RS="^$"                                                 # whole file treated as a single line of input
        regex1="<td>Manual Checks</td>[[:space:]]+<td>0</td>"
        regex2="<td>Failures</td>[[:space:]]+<td>0</td>"
      }
$0 ~ regex1 && $0 ~ regex2 {print FILENAME}
```

**NOTE:** placing the code in a file (`regex.awk`) will make the follow-on `find/awk` quite a bit cleaner

Sample input:

```
$ cat f1.html
... snip ...
                    <td>Failures</td>
                    <td>0</td>                         # match
... snip ...
                    <td>Manual Checks</td>
                    <td>9</td>                         # not a match
... snip ...

$ cat f2.html
... snip ...
                    <td>Failures</td>
                    <td>0</td>                         # match
... snip ...
                    <td>Manual Checks</td>
                    <td>0</td>                         # match
... snip ...
```

**NOTE:** comments added for clarification; comments to not exist in the actual files

Adding this to a `find` call:

```
$ find . -name "f?.html" -exec awk -f regex.awk '{}' \;                                                              
./f2.html
```

Comment: so when you wrote that regex portion do you not have to follow the regex writing convention? like this? \<td\>Manual Checks\<\/td\>

Comment: depends on the program/binary you're writing for and whether or not said program/binary has special processing for certain characters (eg, `<`, `>`, etc); in `awk` you'll find that most characters, when placed between double quotes, are processed as literal characters and hence no need to escape them; in fact, go ahead and add the escapes and you should find that upon running the code `awk` will print a message like `awk: regex.awk:2: warning: escape sequence '\>' treated as plain '>'`

Comment: So how do i become better in awk? Is it just by doing or are there any resources that i can follow? I do watch a few videos on utube about awk but RS and the way AWK processes lines were new to me.

Comment: see [GAWK: Effective AWK Programming.pdf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf); alternatively, the same manual in [html format](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html); links to the `html` version of this document come up quite often when running web searches on a whole host of `(GNU) awk` topics; searching `stackoverflow.com` (and some sister sites) for `awk` and/or `[awk]` will bring up enough Q&A's to keep you busy for quite a long time

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS, other awks would treat it like `RS` was set to the character `^`.

Answer (score 3):

If your html files are well-formed xml, then [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) will work:

```sh
find . -name '*.html' \
       -exec xmlstarlet sel -t \
               --if '//tr[td[1] = "Failures" and td[2] = "0"]' \
               --if '//tr[td[1] = "Manual Checks" and td[2] = "0"]' \
               --inp-name --nl \
             '{}' \;
```

- if there's a row where the first cell is Failures and the second cell is 0,
- and if there's a row where the first cell is Manual Checks and the second cell is 0,
- then print the input filename and a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
gsub("^[[:space:]]*<td>|</td>[[:space:]]*$","") {
    if ( ++cnt % 2 ) {
        tag = $0
    }
    else {
        f[tag] = $0+0
    }
}
END {
    if ( (f["Failures"] == 0) && (f["Manual Checks"] == 0) ) {
        print FILENAME
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
```

The above creates an array `f[]` that maps the tags (names) of the cells to their values so then in the END section you can do whatever test you like on whatever combination of them you like.